# Command with two in files, one out file, looped

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

so here is my dilemma. I have a command in the form:

```
grdpaste infile.grd infile.grd -Goutfile.grd
```

I have a series of folders in the same directory that each contain a file named `infile.grd`. I want to iterate through all the folder so that the first run combines `infile.grd` from the first and second folder, and then the second combines `outfile.grd` from the first run and `infile.grd` from the third folder, and so on. I do not know how many folders exist, and the final product should contain the combination of all the infiles.

I think I can use a counter to control the combination parts (I did it earlier in my script), but I do not know how to make a `for` loop that takes one file from one folder and the other file from the next folder, without knowing the names of the folders. I hope this makes sense, thanks much.

AM

Comment: The final `outfile.grd` is simply the combination of all `infile.grd`. Won't it be any easier if you start with an empty `outfile.grd` and merge with all the `infile.grd`? With this in mind your `for-loop` will be as simple as `for infile in */infile.grd`. If your directory structure isn't flat then a `find . -name infile.grd` is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

If `grdpaste` will accept an empty input file in a sane way then the following should work:

```
lastfile=dummy.grd
touch "$lastfile"
for infile in */infile.grd; do
    _outfile=outfile$((i++)).grd
    grdpaste "$lastfile" "$infile" -G"$_outfile"
    lastfile=$_outfile
done
```

If it can't then the above loop needs to be modified to store the first name it sees in `$lastfile` and do nothing else  that first loop through... something like this:

```
lastfile=
for infile in */infile.grd; do
    [ -z "$lastfile" ] && { lastfile=$infile; continue; }
    _outfile=outfile$((i++)).grd
    grdpaste "$lastfile" "$infile" -G"$_outfile"
    lastfile=$_outfile
done
```

Comment: Hey Etan, I actually just found a solution with writing to a tmp file and then reading it in with a counter. I'll post once it's debugged.

Comment: @amoodie If `grdpaste` is well behaved with its input and ouput and you can correctly use the same file for both input and output in a meaningful fashion then the answer can be greatly simplified. I didn't know if it could and so couldn't count on that and had to write a more "complicated" solution.

Comment: grdpaste is NOT well behaved, so I had to do a pretty dirty method, but it seems to have worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

solution posted below. For complete code, see moravi project [here](https://github.com/amoodie/moravi).

```
for folder in */
    do
    ls "$folder" | sed 's/e/e/' >"${folder%/}.tmp"
done
for file in *.tmp
    do
    lat=$(echo $file | awk -F "." '{print $1}')
    count=0     
    while read line
        do
        count=$(( $count + 1 ))
        if [ "$count" = "1" ]
            then
            declare "tmp_${count}=$line"
        elif [ "$count" = "2" ]
            then
            declare "tmp_${count}=$line"
            prod="P"$(( ${count} - 1 ))".grd"
            grdpaste ./${lat}/${tmp_1} ./${lat}/${tmp_2} -G./${lat}/${prod} -V
        elif [ "$count" > "2" ]
            then
            r="tmp_"${count}
            declare "r=$line"
            pprod="P"$(( ${count} - 2 ))".grd"
            prod="P"$(( ${count} - 1 ))".grd"
            grdpaste ./${lat}/${r} ./${lat}/${pprod} -G./${lat}/${prod} -V
            to_paste=${prod}
        fi
    done <$file
done
rm *.tmp
```